# ajax generating query string automatically after post

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

i am sending ajax request to mvc controller but after the request is finished a query string is appended to my url strange behaviour or am i missing something.
my jquery code.

```
    function addstudent()
    {

        var firstname = $("#firstname").val();
        var lastname = $("#lastname").val();
        var imageuploaded = $("#imageupload")[0].files[0];
        var rememberme = $("#rememberme").is(":checked");
        var newsletter = $("#newsletter").is(":checked");
        var gender = $("input[name=gender]:checked").val();

        var studentDetails = new FormData();
        studentDetails.append("FirstName", firstname);
        studentDetails.append("LastName", lastname);
        studentDetails.append("ImageUploaded", imageuploaded);
        studentDetails.append("RememberMe", rememberme);
        studentDetails.append("IsSubscribed", newsletter);
        studentDetails.append("Gender", gender);

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Student/InsertStudent",
            type:"POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: studentDetails,
            success: onsuccessinsert,
            error:onerrorinsert

        });
        return false;
    }
```

the view has a html button with onclick function

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="studentform" autocomplete="off">
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenid" />
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="firstname" class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" 
name="firstname" placeholder="Enter First Name"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="lastname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Last 
Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" 
placeholder="Enter Last Name"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="imageinput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Image 
Upload</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="imageupload" 
placeholder="Please Select a Image" 
accept="image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/gif,image/png,image/bmp" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="true" > 
 Remember me</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" id="newsletter"> Subscribed To 
 Newsletter</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" 
id="gender1" /> Male</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" 
id="gender2" /> Female</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" 
 onclick="addstudent()" id="insertbtn">Sign in</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

my mvc url before request 
http://localhost:4149/Student
my mvc url after request 
http://localhost:4149/Student?firstname=martin&gender=male

i dont know why its appending a querystring after ajax call. 
my mvc controller code.

```
    public JsonResult InsertStudent(StudentDetails studentDetails)
    {
        try
        {
            string filename = Guid.NewGuid() + 
studentDetails.ImageUploaded.FileName;
            string imagefullpath = Server.MapPath(@"~\ImageUploaded\") + 
filename;
            string imageshortpath = @"WebApplication1\ImageUploaded\" + 
filename;

            studentDetails.ImageFullUrl = imagefullpath;
            studentDetails.ImageShortUrl = imageshortpath;
            studentDetails.ImageName = filename;
            studentDetails.ImageUploaded.SaveAs(imagefullpath);

            return 
 Json(dbcontextStudentDetails.insertstudent(studentDetails), 
  JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
        catch (Exception message)
        {

            return Json(message);
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your button type is `submit` and you have onclick handler on the same button and you are trying to handle form submit in that handler. right?

As your button type is `submit` although your button click handler starts executing, your `HTML Form` will be submitted and thats the reason your URL in browser gets changed.

There are two solution. either hook your `onsubmit` event on `HTML Form`, and in handler and return `false` so it will not submit the form and then you button handler will post the data using ajax or another is change the button type from `submit` to `button`

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="addstudent()" id="insertbtn">Sign in
</button>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: you right i didnt noticed the small behaviour between submit and button thanks.one more thing is that return false is used when we use submit button ?.submit button submits the whole form by default also?

Comment: yes if you are using `type='submit'` then on clicking this button, form will be submitted, but if your are using `type='button'` then it it will not submit the form on click. thats the reason I suggest you to use `type='button'` instead of `type='submit'`  and remember button must be inside `<form>` element else it will not submit the form.